# Merging fields of two index pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I have two data streams in Kibana with similar information. I am trying to aggregate them by creating a new index pattern. Each of them has a field "state". For one of them, the state can be [passed, failed], and for the other one is [Succeeded, Failed]. I want to aggerate passed with Succeeded and failed with Failed. This is my new index pattern:

[image]

when I try to simply visualize the state for the merged index pattern, I get the below chart, which is expected:

[image]

To merge states, I defined a lookup for the merged index pattern as below:

[image]

that I expected to merge the states. But I get this in visualization:

[image]

So my question is, how can I merge the data from both streams?

Answer (score 0):

Using a lookup is not the right way, as it only influences the display value in Kibana. The actual aggregations happens in Elasticsearch. That means it happens before the data reaches Kibana and get mapped to your new values.

What you need to do is:

**OPTION A:**
Use in ingest pipeline for the two index that has the values with capital letters and use the lowercase processor to ingest the data with the same format.

**OPTION B:**
Use runtime fields in your merged index to lowercase all values of the state field into a new field. Then use the new field for the visualization.

The difference between A and B is that a runtime field is evaluated on every search request which takes performance. The advantage is you have it immediately available for all your existing and future data.
Using ingest pipelines you are only influencing the newly incoming data. After changing to the new format you may also want to update the old data.

Here you find more detailed info on [runtime fields](https://elastic-content-share.eu/elastic-runtime-field-example-repository/) (It's my own page)